# When is it appropriate to use a C++11 *_until timeout function instead of the corresponding *_for function?

Tags: c++, c++11, timeout

In C++11, the `*_until` timeout functions behave "as expected" only if a steady clock (i.e., one that moves only forward at an unchanging rate) is used.  Because `system_clock` is not a steady clock, that means that code like this can behave quite surprisingly:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
std::this_thread::sleep_until(system_clock::now() + seconds(10));
```

This will cause the current thread to sleep for 10 seconds unless the system clock is adjusted during the sleep period, e.g., for daylight savings time.  If the clock is set back an hour during the sleep, the current thread will sleep for an hour and 10 seconds.

From what I can tell, every `*_until` timeout function in C++11 has a corresponding `*_for` function that takes a duration instead of a timepoint.  For example, the above code can be rewritten as follows:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(10));
```

The `*_for` functions shouldn't have to worry about clocks that get adjusted while the function is executing, because they just say how long to wait, not what time it's supposed to be when the wait is over.

This issue affects more than sleep functions, as the same is true for timeout-based waits on futures and try_lock functions.

The only situation in which I can envision it making sense to use an `*_until` function with an unsteady clock would be when you *want* to take clock adjustments into account, e.g., you want to sleep until next Wednesday at 3:30AM, even if there's a change to or from daylight savings time between now and then.  Are there other situations where `*_until` functions make more sense than `*_for` functions?  If not, is it safe to say that, in general, the `*_for` timeout functions should be preferred over the `*_until` functions?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the _steadiness_ of the _clock_? Are the `wait_for` and `wait_until` really intended to operate different in their handling of 'clock jumps'?

Comment: @K-ballo: Right, that's why I specifically mentioned clock steadiness and that system_clock is not steady.  The `_for` and `_until` functions behave differently as regards clock adjustments, but what the _intention_ is is not clear to me.

Comment: The _steadiness_ of `system_clock` is actually implementation dependent.

Comment: @K-ballo: Yes, you're right.  I should have said that system_clock is not guaranteed to be steady.  My understanding, however, is that the system_clock is supposed to correspond to wall clock time, meaning that in locales where daylight savings time is observed, it will be adjusted forward and back, and from time to time one would expect it to be adjusted to compensate for time drift on the local machine. In practice, I think it would be uncommon for system_clock to be steady.

Comment: std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(10)); uses a steady clock rather than system_clock, so what you claim in your original question to be equal is in fact not - depending on implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *xxx*`_until` calls are for when you have deadline. The typical use case is where you have a hard time limit for a section of code which either contains multiple waits, or where the time consumed by each step prior to the wait is unpredictable.

e.g.

```
void foo() {
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point const timeout=
    std::chrono::steady_clock::now()+std::chrono::milliseconds(30);

  do_something_which_takes_some_time();

  if(some_future.wait_until(timeout)==std::future_status::ready)
    do_something_with(some_future.get());
}
```

This will only process the value from `some_future` if it is ready within 30ms from the start, including the time taken for `do_something_which_takes_some_time()`.

As in this example, most use cases of the *xxx*`_until` functions will use a steady clock in order to have a predictable timeout.

The only case where I can imagine using the *xxx*`_until` functions with a non-steady clock (such as `std::chrono::system_clock`) is where the timeout is user-visible, and depends on the value of the chosen clock. An alarm clock or reminder program is one example, a backup program that runs "at midnight" is another.

Answer (score 4):

One use-case for the `sleep_until` function is if you want to sleep until a specific time, and not a specific duration.

For example, if you have a thread that should only activate at 3 pm every day, you either have to calculate the duration (including handling daylight saving and leap years) for use with `sleep_for`, or you could use `sleep_until`.

Comment: An alarm clock is an excellent example of something that should take Daylight Saving Time into account. Your working hours are adjusted to DST, and therefore so should your alarm clock.

Answer (score 3):

One good use for `sleep_until` is in steady-time loops (like game loops). If you’re not sure how long a cycle will take to process, but it must *usually* be of a certain minimal length, you can increment the time_point to be slept until by the cycle period. For example:

```
// requires C++14
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
  auto start_time = steady_clock::now();

  for (auto i = start_time; i <= start_time + 1s; i += 50ms) {
    this_thread::sleep_until(i);
    cout << "processing cycle..." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But then you’ve probably got to keep track of lag when a cycle takes *longer* than the increment time.

The idea is, if you naively `sleep_for`, you’ll be sleeping your cycle period *plus* the time it takes to run your in-loop code.