# How to decrement a value over a set amount of time?

Tags: c++, increment, decrement

Basically I need a function that makes x decrement to 0 over a certain time period (40 seconds)
This seems pretty simple in theory but I haven't been able to do it for a bit now.

```cpp
static auto decrement = [](int start_value, int end_value, int time) {
    //i need this function to decrement start_value until it reaches end_value
    //this should happen over a set time as well, in this case 40 seconds.
};

int cool_variable = decrement(2000, 0, 40); //40 seconds, the time should be expected in seconds
```

Comment: Are you imagining that this somehow takes place in the background while other code is running? If so, what would coordinate acceses to `cool_variable` so that later code doesn't read it while it's in the process of being modified?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `cool_variable` will be read and used constantly.
I need the value to be updated constanly, not ever one second or so since it will be used later as the X position of something that will be rendered.

Comment: No it doesn't. On Windows you get `Sleep` with the time specified in milliseconds, and unfortunately Windows doesn't normally provide anything near a clean 1 ms clock tick. On POSIX systems you get `sleep` which ticks in seconds.  `std::this_thread::sleep_for` and it impossibly tight increments, but is still limited by what the target can offer, so you're lucky on a desktop to get a millisecond. Why the tick resolution matters: sleep functions guarantee *at least* the time you ask for and will shoot past by up to the size of the tick.

Comment: Plus you have to worry about the drift caused by whatever code you run after waking up, but unless you do a lot of heavy lifting, it'll probably be less than the overages from the tick.

Comment: You also have to watch out for even more losses from task scheduling. Good timing code is an absolute <expletive deleted> to write as the resolution gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: Why not just compute the correct value of `cool_variable` based on the clock whenever you need its value?

Answer (score 0):

@DavidSchwartz has a great comment that should be considered a serious solution:

> Why not just compute the correct value of `cool_variable` based on the clock whenever you need its value?

That being said, this is an answer to the actual question:  How to write this function:

```
decrement = [](int start_value, int end_value, int time)
```

Where `cool_variable` starts with the value `start_value` and decrements at a steady rate of time until it equals `end_value`, and the total amount of time for this multi-decrement operation is `time` seconds.

This is a function with a *time deadline*.  It is [well-established that for problems with a deadline, one should lean towards `*_until` solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11200763/576911) as opposed to `*_for` solutions in handling the time aspect.  This implies that instead of sleeping *for* some time duration between decrements, we need to sleep *until* it is time to decrement from some value to the next lower value.

The use of `sleep_until` allows a somewhat varying time for each iteration of the decrement loop, while ensuing that the total time of the full loop *closely* approximates the total desired `time`.

To achieve the use of `sleep_until`, we need a (presumably) linear function:

```
duration next_time(int value) {return a0 + a1 * value;}
```

where `next_time(start_value) == 0s` and `next_time(end_value) == seconds{time}`.

We have two equations, and two unknowns: `a0` and `a1`.  We can solve for the two unknowns to create our desired `next_time` function:

```
auto next_time = [&](int value)
    {
        return (value - start_value) * time / (end_value - start_value);
    };
```

Now for each value of `cool_variable`, one can `sleep_until(t0 + next_time(cool_variable))` where `t0` is the time where you want `cool_variable == start_value` (and thus want to sleep for 0 seconds).

The next most important thing (after use of `sleep_until`) is to use `<chrono>`.  `int time` is an error-prone API that has no place in modern C++.  The type of `time` should be a `<chrono>` duration such as `seconds` (or perhaps some other unit of time).  Let's start with `seconds`:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<int> cool_variable = 0;

void
decrement(int start_value, int end_value, std::chrono::seconds time)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto next_time = [&](int value)
        {
            return (value - start_value) * nanoseconds{time} / (end_value - start_value);
        };
    auto t0 = steady_clock::now();
    for (cool_variable = start_value; cool_variable >= end_value; --cool_variable)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_until(t0 + next_time(cool_variable));
        cout << cool_variable << endl;
    }
}
```

- `cool_variable` is stored as an `atomic<int>` so that it can be concurrently read by other threads to avoid undefined behavior.
- The input `time` variable is converted to `nanoseconds` precision in the computation so that the argument to `sleep_until` can be as precise as is practical.
- Note that the current time need only be computed once, prior to the decrement loop.
- Just as an example, `cool_variable` is printed to the terminal on each iteration.  This is of course not necessary, and just used for demonstration purposes.

This can now be called like so:

```
decrement(2000, 0, 40s);
```

It can also be instructive to wrap the call to `decrement` with timing information in order to ensure that it is behaving as intended:

```
auto t0 = system_clock::now();
decrement(2000, 0, 40s);
auto t1 = system_clock::now();
std::cout << (t1-t0)/1s << '\n';
```

This will output each value of `cool_variable` between 2000 and 0 (inclusive), and then say how many seconds it took to do the operation (hopefully 40 in this example).

Finally, one minor simplification can be made:

Since we desire `time` to be `nanoseconds` in the computation, it is actually simpler to simply accept `nanoseconds` in the API, relieving us of the need to convert `seconds` to `nanoseconds` internally:

```
void
decrement(int start_value, int end_value, std::chrono::nanoseconds time)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto next_time = [&](int value)
        {
            return (value - start_value) * time / (end_value - start_value);
        };
    auto t0 = steady_clock::now();
    for (cool_variable = start_value; cool_variable >= end_value; --cool_variable)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_until(t0 + next_time(cool_variable));
        cout << cool_variable << endl;
    }
}
```

The client code need not change at all:

```
decrement(2000, 0, 40s);
```

The `40s` argument will implicitly convert to `40'000'000'000ns` at the call site.  And this is why it is so important to use `<chrono>` types for `time`.  Had we not done this, this final (minor) simplification would not have been minor at all.  It would have required changing client code at the call site, which in real-world applications is often impractical.

### In Summary

- Use `sleep_until`.
- Use `<chrono>`.